# Get ID of a random div by using an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a right-click function with just JavaScript, so I thought I would use a mouseover function, e.g.:

```
mysteryDiv.onmouseover=function(){
    if (rightMBclicked === true)
    {
    console.log(mysteryDiv.id);
    }
}
```

The problem is, I can't figure out how to get 'mysteryDiv', here is the function that creates the blocks (I need to access them), and a few important variables:

```
var blocknum = 0;
var blockmax = 2500;
var blocks = [];

function createBlocks()
    {
    if (blocknum < blockmax)
    {
    blocknum += 1;
    var block = document.createElement("div");
    block.className = "block"; 
    block.id = "block" + blocknum;
    blocks.push(blocknum);
    block.style.width = block_width + "px";
    block.style.height = block_height + "px";
    block.style.cssFloat = "left";
    //block.style.backgroundColor = "#228B22";
    block.style.backgroundImage="url('textures/grass.jpg')";
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(block,container.firstChild);
    createBlocks();
    }
    else
    {
    if (blocknum === blockmax)
    {
    createPlayer();
    paused = false;
    }
    }
    }
```

EDIT:

I'm trying to get the ID of the block (mysteryDiv) that my mouse cursor is over.

Comment: what is this mysteryDiv? post more code please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to handle event for dynamically created your blocks. Please try this ... hope this is what you want ... I am not sure what is `rightMBclicked` ... for the testing case set it to `true`

```
//after this line
block.style.backgroundImage="url('textures/grass.jpg')"; 

//here
block.onmouseover = function(e){

    if (rightMBclicked === true)
    {
        console.log(e);
        console.log(this.id);
    }
};

//before this line
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(block,container.firstChild);
```

Comment: Ah, the importance of 'this.id', totally forgot about that! The best part is, I can stop messing around with that silly 'blocks array'... hahaha!

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, you might need to bind the same event handler to all of your divs.

Something like this:

```
handlerFunction = function(e)
{
        console.log(e)

}

divElements = document.getElementsByTagName("div")

for (i in divElements)
    divElements[i].onmouseover = handlerFunction
```

Of course, maybe you will run into trouble with bubbleling. You might want to be more specific on how your html is structured, so we can be more helpful.